# AutoHotKye - How to switch between system sound sources

Tags: autohotkey

I need to switch sound sources using hotkeys. Scripts like this:

```
F6::
Run, mmsys.cpl
WinWait,Sound
ControlSend,SysListView321,{Down 2}
ControlClick,&amp;amp;Set Default
ControlClick,OK
return

F7::
Run, mmsys.cpl
WinWait,Sound
ControlSend,SysListView321,{Down 5}
ControlClick,&amp;amp;Set Default
ControlClick,OK
return
```

don't work. They just start 'sound devices' window

Answer (score 0):

Requires a library VA:

```
F6::
loop
MsgBox % SwapAudioDevice("Speakers", "Digital Output")

SwapAudioDevice(device_A, device_B)
{
; Get device IDs.
A := VA_GetDevice(device_A), VA_IMMDevice_GetId(A, A_id)
B := VA_GetDevice(device_B), VA_IMMDevice_GetId(B, B_id)
if A && B
{
    ; Get ID of default playback device.
    default := VA_GetDevice("playback")
    VA_IMMDevice_GetId(default, default_id)
    ObjRelease(default) 
    ; If device A is default, set device B; otherwise set device A.
    VA_SetDefaultEndpoint(default_id == A_id ? B : A, 0)
}
ObjRelease(B)
ObjRelease(A)
if !(A && B)
    throw Exception("Unknown audio device", -1, A ? device_B : device_A)
Return default_id == A_id ? device_B : device_A
}
Return
```